# sane way to pass/keep a value throughout a long pipe

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

Assuming i have the following rxjs pipe:

```
start$.pip(
    map((id)=> {}), //I want to save the "id" value to be used in the end of the pipe
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    switchMap(...)//I need the original "id" value here
).subscribe()
```

Is there a way to keep the 'id" value throughout the pip so it can be used at the end of the pipe?

Motivation: It comes often in NGRX effects where i want to use the original payload data of the triggering source action for generating the new action.

Comment: I think you have to pass the id from one operator to the next one throught the whole chain. You can try something like that map(id => ({id: id, data:data}))

Comment: It's hard to say without any context, but I suggest to start with `switchMap` and create a nested pipe inside.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the correct way is to make another closure

```
const processId = (id) => observableOf(id)
  .pipe(
    map(() => { ... }),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    switchMap(...) // Use id here
  );

const getPipe = () => start$
  .pipe(switchMap(processId));
```

Storing local variable as a side effect in `getPipe` is OK, but it can break if `start$` Observable emits more values.

Answer (score 1):

The way suggested by @René Winkler is the right way for short pipes.

If the pipe is long though it can be tedious and somehow can make the code less readable.

One alternative approach can be to create a function (or method) where you define `id` as a local variable that you set within the first `map` so that you can use it at your convenience all along the chain of operators, something like

```
getLongPipe(id) {
  let _id;
  return start$.pipe(
    map((id)=> {_id = id; ....}), //I want to save the "id" value to be used in the end of the pipe
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    switchMap(...)//Here you can use _id
  )
}

getLongPipe(id).subscribe()
```

Comment: You are right. I wrote about input variable while what I had in mind was local variable. See the updated answer.

Comment: This contains a race condition: When another `id` comes along while the first is still being processed, it will screw with your pipeline.

Comment: @Patrick I think your point is not valid. The `pipe` contains `switchMap`. `switchMap` means that as soon as the upstream notifies a new value, the downstream Observable is unsubscribed. So *When another id comes along while the first is still being processed* it is correct to override the `_id` value and start another subscription process. This is exactly what `switchMap` means.

Comment: Right, after the first `switchMap` it should be all right, but before that there's still a race condition. In any case: people looking at this solution might not realise that nuance (just as I did not), and use it in a pipe without `switchMap` - and get a race condition, which is a class of bug which is really hard to find. In general, it's best to avoid mutable state altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The closure seems correct, would like to add a detail gotcha, I boiled down to a base case:

Say you want to get to the end of a stream, and based on something that happened earlier, do this or that. So you use the closure pattern, start with a flag of false, and later in the pipe, set it to true. At the end of the pipe, do this or that depending on the flag. Works nicely.

Problem is, after the first time, if that value got set to true, depending on your use (say, an NGRX effect, which is where I ran into this) it'll be true forever (no surprise, the closure persists) unless something else sets it back to the default (false).

Basic form/fix:

```
stream$ = ( ( my_flag = false ) => {
    return ( otherStream$
        .variousOperators ( ... )
        .do ( x => { 
           my_flag = some_condition_of_x ? true : false
        } )
        .map ( x => my_flag ? a : b )
        .do ( x => {
          my_flag = false; // reset
        } )
        .map ( x => x )
    );
  } ) ();
```

Had a pretty tricky case involving some NGRX effects that was greatly (greatly) simplified by this.

Comment: Mixing reactive and imperative styles is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Well…this advice is going on 5 years old. However, avoiding a simple imperative check when it easily solves the issue could be argued as unnecessary engineering. This pattern held reliably in the app—a big one—for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

`combineLatest` could help here:

```js
const start$ = of(5);
const end$ = combineLatest([
  start$,
  start$.pipe(
    map(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
  )
]);
```

This way, `end$` will give you an array with the `start` value, and the value computed through the `map/switchMap` pipeline.

This will create two subscriptions on `start$` though, so if `start$` comes from expensive side-effects like network requests, throw in a `share()`:

```js
const start$ = of(5).pipe(share());
//                        ^ this right here

const end$ = combineLatest([
  start$,
  start$.pipe(
    map(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
    switchMap(...),
    map(...),
  )
]);
```