# how to access previous mergeMap values from rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I am learning to use RXJS. In this scenario, I am chaining a few async requests using rxjs. At the last mergeMap, I'd like to have access to the first mergeMap's params. I have explored the option using `Global` or `withLatest`, but neither options seem to be the right fit here.

```
const arraySrc$ = from(gauges).pipe(
    mergeMap(gauge => {
      return readCSVFile(gauge.id);
    }),
    mergeMap((csvStr: any) => readStringToArray(csvStr.data)),
    map((array: string[][]) => transposeArray(array)),
    mergeMap((array: number[][]) => forkJoin(uploadToDB(array, gauge.id))),
    catchError(error => of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`))
  );
```

`readCSVFile` is an async request which returns an observable to read CSV from a remote server.

`readStringToArray` is another async request which returns an observable to convert `string` to `Arrays`

`transposeArray` just does the transpose

`uploadToDB` is async DB request, which needs `gague.id` from the first mergeMap.

How do I get that? It would be great to take some advice on why the way I am doing it is bad.

For now, I am just passing the ID layer by layer, but it doesn't feel to be correct.

```
const arraySrc$ = from(gauges).pipe(
    mergeMap(gauge => readCSVFile(gauge.id)),
    mergeMap(({ data, gaugeId }: any) => readStringToArray(data, gaugeId)),
    map(({ data, gaugeId }) => transposeArray(data, gaugeId)),
    mergeMap(({ data, gaugeId }) => uploadToDB(data, gaugeId)),
    catchError(error => of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`))
  );
```

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578014/sane-way-to-pass-keep-a-value-throwout-a-long-pipe

Comment: @picci thanks, but i need to get the ID first from a list. I guess I could wrap it into another pipe, but it seems a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do simply this?

```
const arraySrc$ = from(gauges).pipe(
    mergeMap(gauge => readCSVFile(gauge.id).pipe(
         mergeMap((csvStr: any) => readStringToArray(csvStr.data)),
         map((array: string[][]) => transposeArray(array)),
         mergeMap((array: number[][]) => forkJoin(uploadToDB(array, gauge.id)))
    )),
    catchError(error => of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`))
);
```

You can also wrap the inner observable in a function:

```
uploadCSVFilesFromGaugeID(gaugeID): Observable<void> {
     return readCSVFile(gaugeID).pipe(
         mergeMap((csvStr: any) => readStringToArray(csvStr.data)),
         map((array: string[][]) => transposeArray(array)),
         mergeMap((array: number[][]) => forkJoin(uploadToDB(array, gaugeID))
     );
}
```

In order to do this at the end:

```
const arraySrc$ = from(gauges).pipe(
    mergeMap(gauge => uploadCSVFileFromGaugeID(gauge.id)),
    catchError(error => of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MergeMap requires all observable inputs; else, previous values may be returned.
It is a difficult job to concatenate and display the merging response. But here is a straightforward example I made so you can have a better idea. How do we easily perform sophisticated merging.

```
async playWithBbservable() {
const observable1 = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  subscriber.next(this.test1());
});
const observable2 = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  subscriber.next(this.test2());
});
const observable3 = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.next(this.test3());
    subscriber.complete();
  }, 1000);
});
console.log('just before subscribe');

let result = observable1.pipe(
  mergeMap((val: any) => {
    return observable2.pipe(
      mergeMap((val2: any) => {
        return observable3.pipe(
          map((val3: any) => {
            console.log(`${val}  ${val2}  ${val3}`);
          })
        );
      })
    );
  })
);

result.subscribe({
  next(x) {
    console.log('got value ' + x);
  },
  error(err) {
    console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err);
  },
  complete() {
    console.log('done');
  },
});
console.log('just after subscribe');


 }

  test1() {
    return 'ABC';
  }

  test2() {
    return 'PQR';
  }

  test3() {
    return 'ZYX';
  }
```