# How do I persist a value across RxJS 6 pipe operators?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I want to take a JavaScript/TypeScript object, build an element from it on an HTML page, add a CSS class to make it display, then remove the class after a certain period to remove it from the display. It works fine in the `subscribe` callback with `setTimeout`.

```js
of(recordObj).subscribe(
    (record) => {
        let recordEl = new MyRecord(record)
        console.log('created recordEl ' + recordEl.id);
        recordEl.show();
        setTimeout(_ => {
            console.log('hiding recordEl ' + recordEl.id);
            recordEl.hide();
        }, 4000);
    },
    _ => { console.log('subscribe error', _); },
    () => { console.log('done'); }
);
```

Instead of `setTimeout`, I'd really like to make this an RxJS 6 pipe operator using `delay`. However, I've been unable to create a variable that persists across pipe operators *and* is scoped only to a given record's pass through the pipe.

In all four attempts below, `recordEl` retains only the most recent record. The last `tap` repeats the operations for that record when encountered in each pipe, or, if the null assignment is enabled, throws an error caught at `catch[2]`.

```js
export function displayRecord (hideDelay: number = 5000, recordEl?: MyRecord /* attempt 1 */): OperatorFunction<MyRecord, MyRecord> {
    return (source: Observable<MyRecord>) => {
        let recordEl: MyRecord; // attempt 2
        // return ((recordEl?: MyRecord) => { // attempt 3
            // let recordEl: MyRecord; // attempt 4

            return source.pipe(
                tap((recordObj) => {
                    // create the element
                    recordEl = new MyRecord(recordObj);
                    console.log('created recordEl ' + recordEl.id);
                    recordEl.show();
                }),
                catchError((err, caught) => {
                    console.error('catch[1]', err);
                    return EMPTY;
                }),
                delay(hideDelay),
                tap((recordObj) => {
                    recordEl.hide(true);
                    console.log('destroying recordEl ' + recordEl.id);
                    // recordEl = null;
                    // console.log('destroyed recordEl ', recordEl);
                }),
                catchError((err, caught) => {
                    console.error('catch[2]', err);
                    return EMPTY;
                }),
            );
        // })();
    };
}
```

```js
of(recordObj).pipe(
    displayRecord(4000),
).subscribe(
    () => {},
    _ => { console.log('subscribe error', _); },
    () => { console.log('done'); }
);
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579503/356016) on SO. Though an answer mentions "it can break if start$ Observable emits more values", none of the answers actually address the scenario of more than one marble.

Is this possible, and how? Am I attempting an anti-pattern and should stick to `subscribe` and `setTimeout`?

**CLARIFICATION:**

I want the original record to "fall through", preferably without passing both the `record` and `recordEl` through the pipe. This pipe-of-pipes uses `tap` because it does stuff with the data, but not to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be another approach:

```js
src$.pipe(
  mergeMap(recordObj => {
    let recordEl: MyRecord;

    return of(recordObj).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        recordEl = new MyRecord(recordObj);
        console.log('created recordEl ' + recordEl.id);
        recordEl.show();
      }),
      delay(/* ... */),
      tap(recordObj => {
        recordEl.hide();
      }),
    )
  }),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import {map, tap , delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

DELAY_TIME = 4000;
of(recordObj).pipe(
    map((record) => {
        let recordEl = new MyRecord(record)
        console.log('created recordEl ' + recordEl.id);
        recordEl.show();
        console.log('hiding recordEl ' + recordEl.id);
        return recordEl;
    }),
    delay(DELAY_TIME),
    tap((recordEl) => {
      recordEl.hide();
      console.log('recordEl got hidden' + recordEl.id);
    })
).subscribe();
```

Comment: That does make it look ridiculously simple, and would do the trick in certain situations. I want the original `record` (not `recordEl`) to come out of the pipe, which I've clarified in my question.

Comment: @nshew13 In map operator, you already have access to record. Now you can return record or recordEL. If you want to have both, you can use object and put record and recordEl as properties to return in map operator.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass whatever information you want down the pipe as it is processed. Create the element and insert it into the stream, delay, then remove the element from the stream to leave the stream looking the way it started.

Something like this:

```js
export function displayRecord (hideDelay: number = 5000): OperatorFunction<MyRecord, MyRecord> {
  return (source: Observable<MyRecord>) => 
    source.pipe(
      map(recordObj => {
        // create the element
        recordEl = new MyRecord(recordObj);
        console.log('created recordEl ' + recordEl.id);
        recordEl.show();
        return ({
          record: recordObj,
          element: recordEl
        });
      }),
      delay(hideDelay),
      map(rec => {
        rec.element.hide(true);
        console.log('destroying recordEl ' + rec.element.id);
        return rec.record;
      })
    );
}
```